# Select an array in mysql where equal to id array

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have my table named sup_mon:

```
m_id
1
2
3
4
5
```

lets assume that this post array has 1,2,3 values.

```
$m_id = $_POST['m_id'][$_POST['m_id']];
```

How can i select the m_id from array post which has the value of m_id[1],m_id[2],m_id[3] ?

like:

```
   m_id
    1
    2
    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sup_mon WHERE m_id IN (?)
```

And your bound parameter should be set equal to something like `implode(',', $m_id)`

**Update**

If you're not using bound parameters, this is the SQL you're looking for:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sup_mon WHERE m_id IN (" . implode(',', $m_id) . ")";
```

Although you really should be using bound parameters.

Comment: It should be `implode`

Comment: this output will be comma separated right sir? but i don't want it in comma separated..

Comment: no, the output of the sql command will be a result set.  see my update. all the `implode` is doing is formatting the input for the `IN` clause

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `IN()` clause

```
$sql = "SELECT m_id FROM sup_mon WHERE m_id IN ('".m_id[1]."','".m_id[2]."','".m_id[3]."')";
```